# Continuous function and infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $C\subset \mathbb{R^n}$, and $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on cl$C.$

Prove that 
$$\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}=\inf\{ f(x)|x\in\text{cl}C \}.$$

I tried to use whenever a sequence, $x_n \in C$  converges to $x^* \in\text{cl}C$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x^*)$.

But I have no idea after this... I would really appreciate your help.

$\text{cl}C$ means the closure of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

This could be proven by contradiction. Suppose
$$\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}>\inf\{ f(x)|x\in\text{cl}C \}.\tag1$$
Then there is a $x^*\in\text{cl}C$ such that
$$f(x^*)<\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}$$
Since $x^*$ is in the closure of $C$, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset C$ that converge to $x^*$.

By continuity of $f$, $f(x_n)\to f(x^*)$ as $n\to\infty$. It means for every $\epsilon>0$, there exist a $N_\epsilon$ such that for every $n>N_\epsilon$
$$\lvert f(x_n)-f(x^*)\rvert<\epsilon$$
Let's take 
$$\epsilon=\frac{\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}-f(x^*)}2>0$$
For this $\epsilon$, there is a $N_\epsilon$ such that 
$$n>N_\epsilon\implies \lvert f(x_n)-f(x^*)\rvert<\epsilon$$
This last equation is equivalent to
$$f(x^*)-\epsilon<f(x_n)<f(x^*)+\epsilon$$
By the definition of $\epsilon$ and the right inequality, we have
$$f(x_n)<f(x^*)+\frac{\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}-f(x^*)}2=\frac{\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}+f(x^*)}2<\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}$$
Which is a contradiction since $x_n\in C$. The assumption $(1)$ is false and
$$\inf\{ f(x)|x\in C\}=\inf\{ f(x)|x\in\text{cl}C \}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\inf f(\overline{C})=\inf \overline{f(\overline{C})}=\inf \overline{f(C)}=\inf f(C)$.

Answer (score 0):

(i).If $D\subset E\subset \Bbb R$ then $\inf D\ge \inf E.$

(ii). If $D\subset \Bbb R$ then $\inf D=\inf \overline D.$

(iii).  Since $f$ is continuous we have $ f(\overline C)\subset \overline {f(C)}. $

$$\text {Therefore }\quad (*)\quad\inf f(C)\ge \inf f(\overline C)\ge \inf \overline {f(C)}=\inf f(C). $$ The 1st inequality  in $(*)$ is by (i); the 2nd is by (i) & (iii); the "$=$" is by (ii).